# Komma vor einem mit “als” eingeführten Nebensatz

Tags: comma, comparison

Kommt ein Komma vor "als" in

> Wenn auch in der Praxis eher pragmatischere Methoden und Formalismen eingesetzt werden(,) als sie hier eingeführt werden, so soll doch deutlich werden, dass die Ansätze der Praxis einer vollständigen wissenschaftlichen, formalen Behandlung zugänglich sind.

Ich denke, es kommt ein Komma hin laut § 74 der Rechtschreibregeln, weil "als sie hier eingeführt werden" ein eingeschobener Nebensatz ist. Allerdings finde ich dort keinen vergleichbaren Satz der Form "Wenn auch ..., als ..., so ...  .", dessen Nebensatz "als ..." einem Vergleich dient.

Comment: Das *sie* gehört dort überhaupt nicht hin, meinem Sprachverständnis nach, bzw. ist [es] zumindest überflüssig, ähnlich wie "es" in diesem Satz.

Answer (score 7):

Ja, dies ist ein untergeordneter Vergleichssatz (und nicht etwa ain Temporalsatz) mit Bezug auf den Komparativ *pragmatischer*. Dieser [wird durch Komma abgetrennt](http://www.neue-rechtschreibung.net/2010/04/06/kommasetzung-bei-als/).